# SQL Building Features Using Rolling Window in Non O(N^2) Time

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I am building features on top of a fact table (say invoice history) which will simply keep appending to the right. A basic invoice history table might look like this:

```
|   date     |   customer   | product  | amount  | feature c-p (past 5 days) |  ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2020/01/01 |      CA      |   P1     | 10      |    NA                     |
| 2020/01/02 |      CA      |   P1     | 5       |    10   = 10              |
| 2020/01/05 |      CA      |   P1     | 20      |    15   = 5 + 10          |
| 2020/01/07 |      CA      |   P1     | 20      |    25   = 20 + 5          |
                                                  (01/01 out of range above) |
| 2020/01/15 |      CA      |   P1     | 100     |    25   = 10 + 5 + 20     |
| 2020/01/17 |      CA      |   P1     | 200     |    100  = 100             |
| 2020/01/31 |      CA      |   P1     | 20      |    0    = 0               |
```

At first, we wrote the logic of using a self-join in something similar to:

```
select 
    c.date, 
    c.customer, 
    c.product, 
    c.amount, 
    sum(c.amount2)
from
    (select 
        i1.*,
        i2.date as date2, 
        i2.amount as amount2
    from invoice i1
    inner join invoice i2
    on i1.customer = i2.customer 
    and i1.product = i2.product 
    and i1.date < i2.date and i1.date >= i2.date - 5    -- where we customize the window
    ) c   
group by 
    c.date, 
    c.customer, 
    c.product, 
    c.amount
```

This self-join itself is O(N^2) if I am not mistaken but the logic is very simple for everyone to wrap their head around. But not until lately that this approach exploded when we start working with a big table.

I was thinking about window functions prior but I am not sure if there is a more efficient (computation efficient and storage efficient way) of doing it?

What I had in mind is to use window function but looks my logic is a customized over range just than a fixed looking N rows back, instead it should looking back 5 days back? Is it possible in Hive/Impala, if not, I guess I will have to ***fill in the missing days*** and then use the windows functions. Open to any suggestion?

(Today we are using Hive/Impala, but if there is indeed a more efficient way in other databases, I am certainly open to it).

---

update

Just ran a benchmark of using 20 million rows real data, and the time saving is substantial:

- self join with filtration: 128 minutes
- using window function including date conversion: 15 minutes (Gordon's answer), most importantly, this approach is guaranteed not to introduce duplications as same customer and same product might be bought several times same day
- Hive doesn't support inline correlated subquery but GBM's solution should be efficient to avoid full cartesian join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive supports `range`, but only with numbers I think.  Fortunately, you can convert your dates to numbers and still use it:

```
select t.*,
       sum(amount) over (partition by customer, product
                         order by days
                         range between 5 preceding and 1 preceding
                        )
from (select t.*,
             datediff(date, '2000-01-01') as days
      from t
     ) t;
```

One issue is that it is rather hard to distinguish between 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-31.  Both of these return `NULL`.  If you really want to distinguish them, then you can use `lag()` and `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when datediff(date, prev_date) > 5 then 0
             when prev_date is null then null
             else sum(amount) over (partition by customer, product
                                    order by days
                                    range between 5 preceding and 1 preceding
                                   )
        end)
from (select t.*,
             datediff(date, '2000-01-01') as days,
             lag(date) over (partition by customer, product order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: It is always the edge cases at the beginning and the end. There are several logics like LOCF or LOCB that I am experimenting but thanks for providing your case statement which is a great framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky enough to run a database that supports the `range` clause to window functions with intervals (as does Postgres for example, starting version 11), you can do:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(amount) over(
        partition by customer, product
        order by date
        range between interval '5 day' preceding and interval '1 day' preceding
    ) feature_cp
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=26730da98d2d06925cabe1f051cbe443)**:

```
date       | customer | product | amount | feature_cp
:--------- | :------- | :------ | -----: | ---------:
2020-01-01 | CA       | P1      |     10 |       null
2020-01-02 | CA       | P1      |      5 |         10
2020-01-05 | CA       | P1      |     20 |         15
2020-01-07 | CA       | P1      |     20 |         25
2020-01-15 | CA       | P1      |    100 |       null
2020-01-17 | CA       | P1      |    200 |        100
2020-01-31 | CA       | P1      |     20 |       null
```

---

Otherwise, I would recommend using a correlated subquery. This is a little more efficient than your join query, since it avoids the need for outer aggregation:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select sum(amount) 
        from mytable t1 
        where 
            t1.customer = t.customer 
            and t1.product = t.product
            and t1.date < t.date
            and t1.date >= t.date - interval '5 day'
    ) feature_cp
from mytable t
```

Comment: yeah. sadly inline subquery is not supported in Hive, at least in the version that I am currently using but certainly it looks more efficient than a cross join and then filtration.